# How to write middleware in Savon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

Is there a way to write middleware in Savon like Rack middleware or Faraday middleware?

The only thing a found was [`Observers`](http://savonrb.com/version2/observers.html) but its not what I looking for because savon observer getting called only once before request was made.

In Faraday for example middleware called twice - before request was made and after response was got. So I can do things like calculate time of request/response